# Валидация номера телефона международного формата (C#, ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, валидация

Есть форма, которая принимает телефонный номер любого формата любой страны, кроме рекламных телефонов (вроде Израиля со *).

Например строки могут выглядеть следующим образом:

`+7(###) ###-##-##` - русский номер

`+1 ###-###-####` - США

Телефонный номер в приложении является уникальным идентификатором пользователя на равне с Id и используется для авторизации.

В базе номера записаны числом, но возникла проблема. Например в Республике Беларусь номер могу ввести как в полном международном формате: `+375 (##) ###-##-##`, так и в каком-то своем локальном `80 (##) ###-##-##`.

Код 80 может быть также кодом страны, и это уже будет Италия.

**Существует ли способ провалидировать номер телефона чтобы гарантировать, что он получен из записан в международном формате?**

Comment: https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp смотрели данную библиотеку?

Comment: А зачем вообще допускать ввод локального формата?

Comment: @vitidev так ведь вопрос в том как этого не допустить

Comment: @User да. Она позволяет разбить номер на составные части если знать какая используется страна, а я не могу этого знать заранее. Мне нужно провалидировать сам номер что это номер международного формата, локальные номера страны мне ненужны

Comment: Не начинается с + значит уже не международный формат.

Comment: @vitidev номер возможно записать используя только цифры

Comment: А что вам мешает не принимать номер записанный только цифрами? Вы хотите гарантировать что  номер записан в международном формате, но почему то не хотите требовать этого.

Comment: @vitidev эм, ну так мне и нужно сделать проверку на то что формат международный. + я могу к любому числу подставить, от этого число не станет международным номером телефона

Comment: дайте вашим юзерам выбрать страну, сами подставляйте +(код страны) когда страна выбрана, остальную часть номера просите ввести юзера. Таким образом юзер не сможет ввести локальный номер.